# A model that can fit binary data in R

Tags: r, probability, dataset, binary-data

I have data that indicates if the computers in my network are up or down. Data is collected every minute and has a seasonality of one week, looks like this for 3 hosts.
Servers are supposed to go down less often than workstations.

```
ID TIME STATE TYPE  
1  60   0     workstation  
2  60   1     server  
3  60   0     server  
1  120  1     workstation  
2  120  1     server  
3  120  0     server
```

I am using R and I'm looking for a model that can give me the probability of a host being down or up in a future time interval.
Which model do you think would fit the best these requirements?

I have thought of using duration models with the survival package, considering the host going up and the host going down as events.
What do you think of this ? Are there better candidates?

Comment: The thing with survival models is you don't come back alive after you die; in survival models you change state *exactly once*. This looks nearer to some kind of state-switching model; you might stick a parametric survival-type model on top of a markov-chain model for the state (that is, where the probability of moving from 0->1 or 1->0 is a function of predictors and perhaps thereby have some form of "survival" for each state).

Comment: For survival models, I have heard of the  [frailtypack](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/frailtypack/index.html) that can handle recurent events. I think I also need multiple events in my case (going down and going up), I don't know if the frailtypack can handle this.

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry but I only have a basic knowledge of stats, do you have some hints on how I can implement a survival model on top of a markov model?

Comment: Olivier Sorry, it's not really something I have experience of; I'd have to research the best way to do it myself; the comment was intended to clearly point out it was more complex than a straight survival model.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, survival models would be one choice. These estimate the probability to remain "up" for another period (minute), given the covariates. I guess the only covariate here would be a constant and a workstation dummy. This makes the most sense if computers remain "down" once they are down absent intervention.

Another way that makes more sense if computers go up or down randomly: OLS with autoregressive terms. If a station is down at $t$, it will likely also be down at $t+1$, right? Hence, something like 
$$state_{i,t}=\alpha+\beta_1 state_{i,t-1}+\beta_2 state_{i,t-2}+\beta_3 state_{i,t-3}+\beta_4 workstation+e_i$$ 
might be appropriate (workstation is dummy). Perhaps also add interactions of autoregressive terms with workstation. This would allow you to predict the probability of being up or down in the next minute.

If you want to predict the probability of the state in two minutes, you have to respecify and reestimate the model dropping the $state_{i,t-1}$ terms (since you don't know what the state in the period prior---that is the next---period will be). And so on.

Comment: Yes, a host never goes down for good and will always come back up at some time.
I tried to fit an ols model with autoregressive terms on a binary sample using ar.ols and predict in R but i got an error maybe you can help me.
`dd<-ar.ols(ts(test, frequency=55),order.max=5,method=ols)
ee<-predict(dd,1)`  


`Error in x[n + i - seq_len(p)] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`

Comment: Sorry, I don't use R, but it seems as if $x[n + i - seq_len(p)]$ takes on negative as well as positive values, which it shouldn't?